# Add a column to an existing table using GQL?

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

I have a table having some entries. I want to add a column to that table with some default value.In mysql we it as 
In mysql:

```
`ALTER TABLE Example ADD status VARCHAR(60) default 1`
```

How can I achieve same in `GQL (google query language)?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As google datastore is object oriented, it is different from MySql.
Once you update your existing model by adding new field to your model class:

```
class Example(db.Model):    
    #other fields
    status = db.StringProperty()
```

and

```
example = Example()
example.status = "Happy new year"
example.put()
```

you achieve it.